# How can I sign my ps-script without empty it before?

Tags: powershell, certificate, sign

I created a certificate and it is valid:

```
 Thumbprint                     Subject
 ----------                     -------
 0562....................4944E  CN=Callis PowerShell
```

Now I want to sign my script LoadAndParse.ps1.
 But if I try:

```
 PS C:\...\X> $cert = @(Get-ChildItem cert:\CurrentUser\My -codesigning)[0]
 PS C:\...\X> Set-AuthenticodeSignature  LoadAndParse.ps1 $cert
 Directory: C:\...\
 SignerCertificate                Status          Path
 -----------------                ------          ----
                                  UnknownError    LoadAndParse.ps1
```

If I slightly modify my sequence of orders by adding one command and I get it signed - but now it is empty :(

```
  PS C:\...\X> echo get-location > LoadAndParse.ps1
  PS C:\...\X> $cert = @(Get-ChildItem cert:\CurrentUser\My -codesigning)[0]
  PS C:\...\X> Set-AuthenticodeSignature  LoadAndParse.ps1 $cert

     Directory: C:\...\X

     SignerCertificate             Status       Path
     -----------------             ------       ----
     056260.............E24944E    Valid        LoadAndParse.ps1
```

Now the script has only the key-block - well it is surprising method to secure a script!!

How do I sign a script that is able to do something because the code remains untouched?
Thanks in advance,
Gooly

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution.
PS-ISE saves in Unicode Big Endian which Set-AuthenticodeSignature does not understand.
Use Notepad++ to save the script in UTF-8 and you’re fine.

Sigh, if either the the error hint would point in the correct direction or Powershell would understand it’s own code – it would have saved me several hours!

Here is my script that reminds you about this trap:

```
  <#
  .SYNOPSIS
  check whether the file is in UTF8 and sign it  - otherwise give hint what to do
  but this file has to be signed too eventually
  #>
  [CmdletBinding()] Param (
       [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $True)] [string]$Path,
       [Parameter(Mandatory = $False, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $True)] [int]$Idx=0
  )

  function isUTF8 ( [string]$Path, [int]$Idx )
  {
      [byte[]]$byte = get-content -Encoding byte -ReadCount 4 -TotalCount 4 -Path $Path

      if ( $byte[0] -eq 0xef -and $byte[1] -eq 0xbb -and $byte[2] -eq 0xbf ) { 
         Write-Output "$Path`r`nis UTF8, going to sign it using cert. index: $Idx"
         sign $Path $Idx
      } else {
         [console]::beep(500,600)
         Write-Output "$Path is NOT UTF8!`r`nLoad it in Notepad++ and save it in UTF8 - otherwise it can't be signed"
      }
  }


  function sign ([string]$Path, [int]$Idx) {
    $cert = @(gci cert:\currentuser\my -codesigning)[$Idx]
    Set-AuthenticodeSignature $Path $cert
  }

  isUTF8 $Path $Idx
```

I couldn’t imagine to use a non MS-produt to run a MS-script :(